# Image encoding acceptence changes during run time

Tags: opencv, encoding, deep-learning, ros

I have a camera that feeds data to a deep learning model. This model evaluates the images and returns the objects it finds. The program runs fine for sometime and out of nowhere it shuts down.

```
           mask_rcnn: Traceback (most recent call last):
           mask_rcnn:   File "/home/riwo-rack-pc/GIT/automatic-planthandling/Ros/catkin_ws/src/image_processing/mask_rcnn_ros/nodes/mask_rcnn_node", line 227, in <module>
           mask_rcnn:     main()
           mask_rcnn:   File "/home/riwo-rack-pc/GIT/automatic-planthandling/Ros/catkin_ws/src/image_processing/mask_rcnn_ros/nodes/mask_rcnn_node", line 224, in main
           mask_rcnn:     node.run()
           mask_rcnn:   File "/home/riwo-rack-pc/GIT/automatic-planthandling/Ros/catkin_ws/src/image_processing/mask_rcnn_ros/nodes/mask_rcnn_node", line 114, in run
           mask_rcnn:     self._mask_pub.publish(self.center_mask(result))
           mask_rcnn:   File "/home/riwo-rack-pc/GIT/automatic-planthandling/Ros/catkin_ws/src/image_processing/mask_rcnn_ros/nodes/mask_rcnn_node", line 133, in center_mask
           mask_rcnn:     im, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
           mask_rcnn: cv2.error: /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-opencv3-3.3.1/modules/imgproc/src/contours.cpp:199: error: (-210) [Start]FindContours supports only CV_8UC1 images when mode != CV_RETR_FLOODFILL otherwise supports CV_32SC1 images only in function cvStartFindContours_Impl
```

I have looked into the difference in the encoding and posibilities to convert mono8 to the required CV_8UC1. The conclusion seemd to be that they are more or less the same.

```
        rate = rospy.Rate(self._publish_rate)
        while not rospy.is_shutdown():
            if self._msg_lock.acquire(False):
                msg = self._last_msg
                self._last_msg = None
                self._msg_lock.release()
            else:
                rate.sleep()
                continue

            if msg is not None:
                np_image = self._cv_bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(msg, 'mono8')
                np_image = cv2.merge((np_image, np_image, np_image))

                # Run detection
                results = self._model.detect([np_image], verbose=0)
                result = results[0]
                result_msg = self._build_result_msg(msg, result) #TODO

                self._result_pub.publish(result_msg)
                self._mask_pub.publish(self.center_mask(result))


                # Visualize results
                if self._visualization:
                    vis_image = self._visualize(result, np_image)
                    cv_result = np.zeros(shape=vis_image.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
                    cv2.convertScaleAbs(vis_image, cv_result)
                    image_msg = self._cv_bridge.cv2_to_imgmsg(cv_result, 'bgr8')
                    vis_pub.publish(image_msg)

            rate.sleep()

    def center_mask(self, result):
        centers = xyz()
        pt = Point()

        ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(result['masks'], 0, 255, 0)
            #
        im, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
        if(contours != []):
            for c in contours:
                print("in the forloop met contouren")
                M = cv2.moments(c)

                if(M["m10"] and M["m01"] and M["m00"]) != 0:
                    cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
                    cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])

                    print("cx: ", cX)
                    print("cy:", cY)
                    pt.x = cX
                    pt.y = cY
                    pt.z = 0

                    centers.points.append(copy.deepcopy(pt))
        else:
            print('no pot found else')
            pt.x = 0
            pt.y = 0
            pt.z = 0
            centers.points.append(copy.deepcopy(pt))

        return centers
```

I expect the code to keep running until i stop it and i expect the encoding of the message that i am evaluating not to change with out an apparent reason.

Is there a function that can convert this, or is it possible to check the encoding before passing it to the findContours funtion?

Answer (score 0):

This was not an issue caused by the encoding of the image. When the model finds more than one mask in the image the thresh changes to something that can not be processed by the findContours function.